# error using import in webpack. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an issue with webpack. im using `webpack-dev-server` but when i try to run It im having this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` trying to figure it out since yesterday but no luck.

I already tried to export default on other files still got the same issue when importing.

./sort.js
this is my export

```
     export {descend, ascend};
```

./index.js
this is my import

```
    import {descend, ascend} from './js/insertion_sort';
```

./babelrc
this is babel

```
    {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-env"]]
    }
```

webpack.config.js
this my webpack config

const path = require('path');

const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
 entry: './src/index.js',
 output: {
 path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
 filename: 'bundle.js',
 publicPath: '/'
},
module: {
 rules: [
  {test: /\.scss$/, use: 'scss-loader'},
  {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
 ]
},
devServer: {
 contentBase: './'
 }
};
```

im not using the bundle btw. im just using index file as my main.

**UPDATE**

so guys this is so weird. what i did. on my html.index is this i change the script tag to  `<script src="./src/index.js"></script>` to `<script src="./bundle.js"></script>` then its working. but on my package.json i havent built it yet. i was just running it. `"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot"` how would webpack now where to look for `bundle.js` when its not ceated yet. crazy

Comment: As I can see, you have file named sort.js, but importing modules from file instertion_sort, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Try `export default {descend, ascend};`

Comment: hey guys I have an update. it working now but can you explain it? im curious. thank you so much though

Comment: When you run webpack-dev-server it's automatically build all your presets and rebuild them on file changes if hot-reload option is enabled.

Comment: @Andellys even though i didn't explicitly did this? ` "build": "webpack --mode production",` sorry didnt understand your answer.

Comment: @artoo, yep. 'npm start' command runs webpack-dev-server. When it runs it looks at your webpack.config.js file. From this file dev-server understands how to build your app, output file name and other options. Then it build your app using this options and start web-server to serve it. If hot-reload enabled webpack-dev-server also will watch for a changes in your app, which means if you change any file - webpack-dev-server will automatically rebuild it and serve it with new changes. This all gonna work even if you haven't "build" command in your package.json

Comment: @Andellys thank you so much. this is really helpful. as i was so curios how webpack knows about it. thanks

Comment: @artoo glat to help ya ;)